# ng-class does not take effect until the element is not hovered

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have the following code:

```
 <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#some-id"> 
                <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="ctrl.test() ? 'glyphicon-minus-sign': 
               'glyphicon-plus-sign'">
            </span>
</span>
```

Than, in the controller:

```
ctrl.test = function () {
  var el = document.getElementById('some-id');
  return el.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
 };
```

The problem here is, when clicking on the span, the ng-class is working, but only if I remove the mouse pointer from there.. only then the class "glyphicon-plus-sign" or "glyphicon-minus-sign" is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.test = function() {
        const el = document.getElementById('demo');
        $scope.isCollapsed = el.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true';
    }
});
</script>

  <span class='glyphicon'
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#demo"
        ng-class="{'glyphicon-plus-sign' : isCollapsed, 'glyphicon-minus-sign' : !isCollapsed}"
        ng-click="test()">
    <span id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </span>
  </span>

</body>
</html>
```